ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' in virtual environment of my jupyter notebook
I'm using Windows 10 64-bit and Python 3.7.9.

I've set up a virtual environment for my Jupyter notebook.
I've already used pip install scikit-learn, and it's shown when I use pip list.
enter image description here
However, when I try to import sklearn, the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' is shown.
How can I fix this error?

You installed Scikit-learn somewhere in the venv but it isn't where Jupyter is using. Did you try running %pip list inside Jupyter in a new cell? You should get a more accurate picture of what it sees as installed with %pip list. The magic symbol is important. At this point, you can run %pip install scikit-learn in a new cell in the running Jupyter .ipynb file where you want to use it. Or sort out how to properly connect Jupyter to the envionment you are seeing about in your venv info, like ...

 here. (Also see here.
